# Can i change the value of std map without finding it first

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

This is how currently i am changing the value of std::map

```
std::map<std::string, int> stdmapMasks;
stdmapMasks.insert(std::make_pair("VALUE", 1));
std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = stdmapMasks.find('VALUE'); 
if (it != stdmapMasks.end())
    it->second = 42;
```

Can i change the value directly without the need to find the map element ?

Comment: How do you expect to find what you want to change, "without the need to find the map element"?

Comment: It depends. If the key doesn't exist do you want to add it?

Comment: Consider operator[] if you already know it exists

Comment: @Retired Ninja no i do not want to add it.

Comment: It would depend. From your minimal example, yes, you could just use the return of `insert` to change it. If some other module inserted it then you'd have no other options but to find it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ has many ways to interact with a map's values without *explicitly* calling `map::find`. `operator[]` allows you to access a value, default constructing it if it does not exist. `insert_or_assign` from C++17 provides a way to do what `operator[]` does, save for the requirement of having a default constructor. C++17's `try_emplace` will emplace-construct the value if the key is not present, but does nothing if there is already a value there.

But no version of C++ has a method like "try_assign", where assignment doesn't happen if the key already exists. So you will have to explicitly find it first.